# Get Context in java class and service

Tags: java, android

I have an app that check for locations.
In order to get Location and more data, I'm using java class called `UpdateTimesActivity` (it's not an activity)

Now, i want to check the location every 7 hours, and update the data accordind to it, so i have a service doing that. the problem is, that when calling `UpdateTimesActivity`, I'm getting :

```
 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
```

Here is my service:

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, " MyService Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ArrayList<Date> times = (ArrayList<Date>) intent.getExtras().get("requiredTimesToNotify");
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    new UpdateTimesActivity(getApplicationContext(), locationManager);
    BroadcastReceiver resultTimeRevicer = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
            ArrayList<Calendar> resultTimes= (ArrayList<Calendar>) intent.getExtras().get("a");
            if(resultTimes.size()>0){
                    Toast.makeText(context, resultTimes.size()+" " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(resultTimeRevicer, new IntentFilter("times_gabi"));
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

And here is the problem part:

```
public UpdateTimesActivity(final Context context, LocationManager locationManager) {
    this.context = context;
    this.locationManager = locationManager;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, 
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, 
   Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}
                    , 10);
        }

        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, locationListener);


}
```

Now, I did see answers that explain that you can't send context throw service,
But even when i try to do something like 
(When I'm calling it directly from MainActivity it does work)

```
MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
context = m.context (static);
```

and put it in the requestPermissions it won't work.

Thanks...

Comment: new UpdateTimesActivity(getApplicationContext(), locationManager);    YOu can't do that.  You don't create activities via new, you create them via startActivity().  Using new does not initialize them properly.

Comment: And NEVER put an activity into a static variable.  That's a memory leak, and a bad one.

Comment: Also, you can't have a service do something every 7 hours.  It will be killed long before then.  Background services have a few minutes before they're stopped.  You need a JobScheduler set every 7 hours.  Really this entire code needs to be thrown out and rewritten, and you need to follow some more tutorials on how to write an Android app.  This code isn't salvagable to make a question out of, it needs to be rewritten entirely.

Comment: why? JobScheduler use keep the service run on background, i don't need it. i use alarmService to call my srvice, that will update that data 3 times a day. 2nd, i didn't use Activity as static, i made the contex there as static, and just for trying to get it, cause i haven't found any other way. why would it cause a memory leak?   is there anyway to get contex in service?

Comment: A Service is a context.  And JobSchedulers don't keep a service running, it tells the OS to run a component of your app at a certain time.  Let me repeat-  you don't know what you're doing,you don't understand the Android OS, and you're doing almost everything wrong.  You need serious study on how the OS works before attempting this again, there's nothing salvagable in your approach.

Comment: it works, thank you for your help. i just made the requestPremission at the mainActivity and everything fine. you have a recomended taturial for learning services better?